# Add an element in a list by matching with a regex

Tags: c#, regex, list

I am an intern and I am developing a solution in C# which allows me to retrieve a string of characters in a cell from an excel file. Once this string has been retrieved, the elements of this string must be separated into 2 other lists (sample and reference) using a regex.
It means that if an element of this string corresponds to the regex, it must be sent in the "sample" list and if it does not correspond, it must be sent in the "reference list".

For several days, I have been trying to fix this problem but I cannot display the "sample" list where the elements should correspond to the regex. It does not work correctly, whether the whole list is displayed or nothing is displayed.

Examples of string of characters :

Example 1:

`QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ;`

Example2 :

`; C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2 ; Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ;`

and here is my code :

```
public static (List<string> sample, List<string> reference) parse()
{
    string imput = ReadExcel();

    List<string> sample = new List<string>();
    List<string> reference = new List<string>();

    string pattern = @"C-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-S-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ;";

    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    Regex delim = new Regex(@"\s*,\s*");

    foreach (string term in delim.Split(imput))
    {
        if (rgx.IsMatch(term))
        {
            sample.Add(term);
            sample.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
        else
        {
            reference.Add(term);
        }
    }

    return (sample, reference);
}
```

I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me ?

Thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: Are the example "sample" or "reference" ?

Comment: did you mean split by `\s*;\s*` ?

Comment: The examples I gave, are the examples of the initial string of characters which is the excel file at the begining. I have to split this string in two list sample and reference by matching with a regex.

Comment: In a other post in stackoverflow, I was advised to split before doing the regex match with "\s*;\s* "     i don't know if it is the best option.

Comment: but in the code you are splitting on a comma `\s*,\s*` not a semicolon `;`

Comment: Thank you very much it's the reason why it was a difficult to display the list but there is another problem now, when I run the program to display the reference list to see if the program is working correctly there is an infinite loop that appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this regex :

```
C-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-S-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ;
```

To match this :

```
C-210104-S-117 2
```

You can simply use this regex :

```
C-[0-9]{6}-S-[0-9]{3} [0-9]
```

I put some example in the tool [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kOZTPK/1)

Edit : And to split elements in a list I wouldn't use a regex, I would use the ".Split" method available on string objects.

```
myRow.Split(';')
```

Edit2 : So the code could looks like :

```
        List<string> sample = new List<string>();
        List<string> reference = new List<string>();
        string pattern = @"C-[0-9]{6}-S-[0-9]{3}( [0-9])?";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        foreach (string term in input.Split(';').Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
        {

            if (rgx.IsMatch(term))
            {
                sample.Add(term);
                sample.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }
            else
            {
                reference.Add(term);
            }
        }
```

But I don't get why the Console.WriteLine after adding the sample ?

Comment: Thank you, and for the first example it can be the same regex ?

Comment: Your refex is not working because there is a space before the last digit and you do not take care of it in your regex. Mine seems to work for the cases I tested.
So you can take the whole cell content, split using the "split" method available with string then for each element you can use the regex I provide to determine if it's a sample. You will maybe need to ".Trim()" the value to remove space before/after each element.

Comment: I adjust my answer to show you what the code could looks like

Comment: I just edited my answer for two reasons : 1) to remove empty element (the space alone after the last ";" will be considered as an element) and 2) to adapt the regex because it seems the sample are not the same in your two lists. Sometimes there is an additional digit and sometimes not.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just saw your edit, that's why i deleted my previous comment. I'm sure it will work correctly now. 
"But I don't get why the Console.WriteLine after adding the sample ? [1]:" : I did thisjust to check if the code is working correctly. But I will remove this line later.

Comment: You can use breakpoint if you want to make your debugging waaaaay easier :-)

Comment: :-) Don't hesitate to put the answer as "accepted".